# How to put default avatar for a user

Tags: django, templates, model

How can I put default avatar for a user when user does not put their own image?

This is my template.

`ifequal` statement does not work.

```
{% for each_model in Result %}

<div class="panel panel-success" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:50px ;margin-top:100px;width:400px ;float:right">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title"style="text-align:center"><strong>USER INFORMATION</strong></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

         {% ifequal each_model.Profile_image blank %}
           <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/Profile_image/deafult-profile-image.png"/>
                <hr>
            {% else %}
                 <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{each_model.Profile_image}}"style="width:300px; height:200px; display:block; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
                    <hr>
        {% endifequal %}
```

This is my model

I tried to put default in the field, it is not working.

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
   email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='Email',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,null = False
)
username = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = False)

Nationality =models.CharField(max_length = 30,choices= Country_choice,null = False )
Mother_language = models.CharField(max_length = 30,choices= Language_list,null = False)
Wish_language =models.CharField(max_length = 30,choices= Language_list,null = False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
Profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images',blank=True, default= 'profile_images/deafult-profile-image.png')
status_message=models.CharField(max_length = 500,null = True)
objects = MyUserManager()



USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','Nationality','Mother_language','Wish_language','Profile_image','status_message']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
 {% if not each_model.Profile_image %}
       <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/Profile_image/deafult-profile-image.png"/>
            <hr>
        {% else %}
             <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{each_model.Profile_image}}"style="width:300px; height:200px; display:block; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
                <hr>
    {% endifequal %}
```

But I would suggest you to have a method for your user model which will return the user avatar and use that method in template:

```
# in MyUser model
def get_avatar(self):
   if not self.Profile_image:
       return "YOUR DEFAULT IMAGE"
   else:
       return return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.Profile_image.name)

# and in template:
<img src={each_model.get_avatar} />
```